# How to check a dialog component is on top of dialogs?

Tags: reactjs

i am coding a `Dialog` component, and it will allow to close by pressing the `Esc` key on the keyboard and it works fine.

The problem I have is when using multiple Dialogs on top of each other, when I press `Esc` they all get closed while I just want to close the top Dialog one by one.

The point is know the dialog **isOnTop** or **isNotOnTop** and blocking keyboard event. I have tried using props drilling to check if `DialogB` is opened then `DialogA` **isNotOnTop** and prevent to closing but with more complex components this method seems difficult.

Can anyone give me some suggestions on how to implement my idea in a better way? I'm a newbie with reactjs, thanks.

This is how the idea looklike: [youtube](https://youtu.be/LPuUiTIyYlY)

Below code is written on codesanbox.

[image: Edit funny-rain-1cyn9y]

Comment: You could maintain a array of refs such that whenever a modal is opened you will push ref of that modal into array. This way you will know how many modals are opened. The one at the top will be the last element in your array. So when modal is closed you can call onClose method of that last element and pop it off from the array.

Comment: @PratikWadekar I thought about it before, but when putting 2 Dialogs in the same level, they don't work correctly, same situation happens with @_m_wer answer, [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-shtern-u0oqcu?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around a bit. I used [zustand.js](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand) to store all the opened dialogs.
Every dialog has its own identifier/index. When pressing ESC the dialog checks the open dialogs in the store against its own identifier, like that only the last dialog closes. I used a Set(), so the dialogs are always unique.
I hope that helps.
Here's your modified [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-framework-f8syx8?file=/src/App.js).

**edit**:

(Answering your comment)

This happens because right now the code checks the identifier against the size of the Set. To fix replace this line

```
if (dialogs.size === identifier && event.keyCode === escapeKeyNumber) {
```

with

```
if ([...dialogs].pop() === identifier && event.keyCode === escapeKeyNumber) {
```

this compares the last entry of the set with the identifier instead of the size of the set.

modified [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-shockley-que5kp?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I have problem when putting DialogB and DialogC inside DialogA. The `Esc` function works very strange.  here is the edited [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-shtern-u0oqcu?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @Tuan check my edited answer. hope it helps!

Comment: I thing we missing this case `{isShowX && (<DialogX />)}`, i need to add `removeDialog` to `useEffect cleaner`, but it working after all, thanks for your help.